# Azure NodeJS Function + Azure App Service issue with Get Request

Tags: php, node.js, azure, function, azure-web-app-service

I have a Azure Function running on a timer Trigger.

```
const { app } = require('@azure/functions');

app.timer('Cron', {
    schedule: '0 0 */1 * * *',
    handler: async (timer, context) => { // 2
        const url = 'https://xxx/backup/index.php';
        const headers = {
            'key': 'key'
        };
    
        await fetch(url, { headers })
        .then(resp => resp.text())
        .then(data => { context.log(data); })
        .catch(err => { context.log(err); });
    }
});
```

This performs a get request to a PHP file sitting on App Services that performs a backup.

If I hit the URL manually via web browser https://xxx/backup/index.php, the backup file gets created.

However, when the Azure function runs, the backup file doesn't get generated. I can see in the nginx access logs the request from the Azure Function and the HTTP code is 200.

The PHP file just creates a mysql dump when it is requested. There is no authentication yet (so ignore the custom headers in the nodejs code).

Am I missing something?

I've tried running the code manually via the Azure Portal in the Functions Code/Test editor but still the same result. Successful request to the Apps service but not backup file generated.

this is the nginx log when i hit the url manually via browser

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [03/Dec/2023:09:12:41 +0000] "GET /backup/ HTTP/1.1" 200 100 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

this is the log when the azure function runs

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [03/Dec/2023:07:17:00 +0000] "GET /backup/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 31 "-" "undici"
```

this is the php backupscript that runs on AppService

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__, '../../.env');
$dotenv->load();

$host                 = $_ENV['DB_HOST'];
$username             = $_ENV['DB_USERNAME'];
$password             = $_ENV['DB_PASSWORD'];
$database             = $_ENV['DB_DATABASE'];
$encryption_key       = $_ENV['ENCRYPTION_KEY'];
$ssl_cert             = $_ENV['MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'];

$encFile = './backup-'.date('d-m-Y') .'.sql.gz.enc';

// MySQL dump command, gzip, and encrypt in a single pipeline
$command = sprintf(
  'mysqldump --no-tablespaces --ssl=1 --ssl-ca=%s -h %s -u %s -p%s %s | gzip -9 | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -k %s > %s',
  $ssl_cert,
  $host,
  $username,
  $password,
  $database,
  $encryption_key,
  $encFile
);

// Execute the pipeline
exec($command, $output, $exitCode);

if ($exitCode !== 0) die("Backup failed with exit code $exitCode\n");

echo "Backup completed successfully. Filename: $encFile\n";
?>
```

Comment: Can you share your backup/index.php code?

Comment: sure, have added the script in description

Comment: try adding error handling to your PHP script to log any errors that might occur during the backup process. This can help you identify issues with the script execution.

Answer (score 0):

*I made some changes to your code and can generate the backup file from both PHP and timer trigger function code.*

**Code :**

***backup-index.php :***

```php
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();

$result = generateBackup();

if ($result) {
    echo "Backup triggered successfully";
} else {
    echo "Failed to trigger backup";
}

function generateBackup() {
    try {
        $host           = $_ENV['DB_HOST'];
        $username       = $_ENV['DB_USERNAME'];
        $password       = $_ENV['DB_PASSWORD'];
        $database       = $_ENV['DB_DATABASE'];
        $encryptionKey  = $_ENV['ENCRYPTION_KEY'];
        $sslCert        = $_ENV['MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'];

        $backupFileName = 'backup-' . date('d-m-Y') . '.sql.gz.enc';
        $backupFilePath = '<path/to/backup_file>' . $backupFileName;

        $mysqldumpPath = 'C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/bin/mysqldump'; 
        $zipPath = 'C:/Program Files/7-Zip/7z.exe';

        $command = sprintf(
            '"%s" --no-tablespaces --ssl=1 --ssl-ca=%s -h %s -u %s -p%s %s | "%s" a -si -tgzip -mx=9 -an | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -k %s > %s',
            $mysqldumpPath,
            $sslCert,
            $host,
            $username,
            $password,
            $database,
            $zipPath,
            $encryptionKey,
            $backupFilePath
        );

        exec($command, $output, $exitCode);

        error_log(implode("\n", $output)); 

        return $exitCode === 0;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        error_log('Exception: ' . $e->getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

***.env :***

```php
DB_HOST="<server_name>.mysql.database.azure.com"
DB_USERNAME="<user_name>"
DB_PASSWORD="<password>"
DB_DATABASE="<db_name>"
ENCRYPTION_KEY="<key>"
MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA="path/to//DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt.pem"
```

***timerTrigger.js :***

```js
const { app } = require('@azure/functions');

app.timer('Cron', {
    schedule: '0 */5 * * * *', 
    handler: async (timer, context) => {
        const url = 'http://xxxxxxx/backup-index.php'; 
        const headers = {
            'key': 'key'
        };
        try {
            const fetch = await import('node-fetch');
            
            const response = await fetch.default(url, { headers });
            const data = await response.text();

            context.log('Backup triggered successfully. Response:', data);
        } catch (error) {
            context.log('Failed to trigger backup. Error:', error.message);
        }
    }
});
```

**Output :**

The PHP code runs successfully as below,

[image]

It generated a backup file as below.

[image]

The timer trigger function triggered successfully and generated a backup file.

[image]